# Codeigniter return Undefined variable codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to send a array data from a controller to a view.
but, a log of the framework accuse: Message: Undefined variable: var.

this is the "fake data" of my controller, the "n":

```
class Produtos extends CI_Controller{


public function index()
{
    $n= [];
    $form = [
        "greetings" => "welcome",
        "user" => "Name:",
        "password" => "Pass:",
        "copyright" => "2016"
    ];

    array_push($n, $form);

    $dados = ["n" => $n];

    $this->load->view("n/index.php");
}
```

}

and, my view named "n" have only a var_dump:

```
<?= var_dump($n);>
```

someone can help?

Comment: the PHP tags are incorrect.This is correct `<?=var_dump($n);?>`

Answer (score 2):

You can check out [CodeIgniter documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html)  . **You should** pass your data to the view, as second parameter to the `$this->load->view` function

```
$form = [
    "greetings" => "welcome",
    "user" => "Name:",
    "password" => "Pass:",
    "copyright" => "2016"
];

$this->load->view("n/index.php", ["n" => $form]);
```

Then, your `var_dump` code is not correct, you should use [php tags](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) in a proper way

```
<?=var_dump($n)?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the elements from your passed array:

In your controller:

```
$this->load->view("n/index.php", $form);
```

In your view:

```
<?php
    echo $greetings; // welcome

    echo $user; // Name:
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just user normal array like below

[The Loading Of Views](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html)

```
class Produtos extends CI_Controller{

public function index()
{
    $data = array(
        "greetings" => "welcome",
        "user" => "Name:",
        "password" => "Pass:",
        "copyright" => "2016"
    );


    $this->load->view("view_file_name", $data);
}

}
```

> I would not use index.php as a name for a view file because you have
>   index.php file in main directory

And then

```
<?php echo $copyright;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your view once.

```
<?= var_dump($n[0]) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didnot have passed the array into the view page.

```
<?php 

    $n= [];
            $form = [
                "greetings" => "welcome",
                "user" => "Name:",
                "password" => "Pass:",
                "copyright" => "2016"
            ];

            array_push($n, $form);

            $dados = ["n" => $n];
            $this->load->view("index.php",$dados);


        ?>
```